# Annoying SocketTimeoutException when debugging GEA

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have Android app with GAE backend. I'm encountering `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`, probably due to fetch time limitations of GAE.

However, operations I'm doing there is writing pretty simple object into datastore and returning it to the user. Debug time, that eclipse generates makes it too long I guess...

What would be the way to increase timeout time in such usage:

```
Gameendpoint.Builder builder = new Gameendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);
Gameendpoint endpoint = builder.build();

try {
    Game game = endpoint.createGame().execute();;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so, how?

Comment: Kinda did. Posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a silly mistake. The limit of such operation is 30 seconds, which should be enough. However, inside createGame() there was an infinite loop. I have a feeling that GAE framework recognizes such situation and causes SocketTimeoutException before 30 seconds actually passes.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets on endpoints have a 2000 ms timeout. This is ample time if you are running short processes: a quick query(continuous queries handled differently), or a write operation. If you overload the process and try to do too much (My issue) then you will get this error. what you need to do it run a lot of different endpoint operations and not try to handle too much at one time. You can override the timeout with the HTTP transport if needed but it is not advised.